# Pandas: Calculate column mean values for hourly data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like this('Timestamp' is in `datetime type` and index col.) :

```
                                    Server Citta Nazione  download Mb/s  upload Mb/s     ping            Isp
Timestamp                                                                                                   
2020-04-01 11:02:04        AlternatYva srl  Rome   Italy      12.550000     0.890000   70.918  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-01 11:04:12        AlternatYva srl  Rome   Italy      10.880000     0.510000   64.908  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-01 11:06:07            Fastweb SpA  Rome   Italy      11.200000     0.650000   63.223  Warian S.R.L.
2020-03-23 05:00:13            Fastweb SpA  Rome   Italy      13.956026     0.629037   31.809  Warian S.R.L.
2020-03-23 05:02:08        AlternatYva srl  Rome   Italy      10.887535     0.224637   31.200  Warian S.R.L.
...                                    ...   ...     ...            ...          ...      ...            ...
2020-04-07 09:03:37        AlternatYva srl  Rome   Italy      12.560000     1.030000   55.119  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-07 09:05:12            Fastweb SpA  Rome   Italy      13.640000     0.770000   29.715  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-25 02:01:52        AlternatYva srl  Rome   Italy      10.990000     0.040000   74.318  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-25 02:03:28  Telecom Italia S.p.A.  Rome   Italy      11.510000     1.090000  137.830  Warian S.R.L.
2020-04-25 02:04:56  Telecom Italia S.p.A.  Rome   Italy      12.960000     0.330000   65.324  Warian S.R.L.

[6726 rows x 7 columns]
```

I want to create a new df with the download mean value from 'download Mb/s' column per hour. Two column HOUR - mean value. Something like:

```
HOUR   mean
0       12.
1       13.5
2        4.8
3        9.6
...
23      10.2
```

Up to now I'm able to calculate by `mean()` function the value of the column 'download Mb/s' of main dataframe. And I understand that with `between_time()` function I can select all the rows between hours of the index column 'Timestamp'.

What is the correct way to aggregate together the two functions to obtain a dataframe as described above?

Answer (score 3):

You can groupby:

```
df.groupby(df.index.hour)[['download Mb/s', 'upload Mb/s']].mean()
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index.hour)` was what I was looking for ;-)

Comment: I think if this answers helped you, then you should mark this answer as accepted as It will be more helpful for others in future. Thanks.